# Sending Email Upon dbFailOnError in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

Essentially I want to send an email once the VBA code stops on *dbFailOnError* I understand I can use the code below to send the email:

```
Set appOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set MailOutLook = appOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        With MailOutLook
            .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
            .To = "test@test.com"
            ''.cc = ""
            ''.bcc = ""
            .Subject = "Test"
            .HTMLBody = "Test"
            .send
```

But how do I trigger the email to send once the code stops at dbFailOnError below:

```
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("Test")
qdf.Parameters![Test] = RST_Invoice!Test
qdf.ReturnsRecords = False
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
intresult = qdf.RecordsAffected
qdf.Close
Set qdf = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Try error handler code.

```
On Error GoTo SubErr

Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("Test")
qdf.Parameters![Test] = RST_Invoice!Test
qdf.ReturnsRecords = False
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
intresult = qdf.RecordsAffected

SubExit:
   qdf.Close
   Set qdf = Nothing
   Set dbs = Nothing
   Exit Sub

SubErr:
   If Err.Number = 3127 Then
      'call email code here
   End If
   Resume SubExit
```